# Getting Error while running Cucumber Runtime as None of the features at [classpath:src/A\B\Feature1.Feature] matched the filters: [@Scenario1]

Tags: java

```
ClassLoader classLoader=getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourceLoader resourceLoader=new MultiLoader(classLoader);
RuntimeOptionsFactory roFactory=new RuntimeOptionsFactory(getClass());
RuntimeOptions ro=roFactory.create();
ro.getGlue().clear();
ro.getGlue().add("classpath:C:\\Users\\Cucumber\\src\\applications\\StepDefinitions\\");    
ro.getFeaturePaths().clear();
String feature = "classpath:src/applications\\Features\\Feature1.Feature";  
ro.getFeaturePaths().add(feature);
ro.getFilters().add("@Scenario1");
ClassFinder classFinder=new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader,classLoader);
cucumber.runtime.Runtime runtime=new cucumber.runtime.Runtime(resourceLoader,classFinder,classLoader,ro);
try {    
runtime.run();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

### Error on Running

> None of the features at
>   [classpath:src/applications\Features\Feature1.Feature] matched the
>   filters: [@Scenario1]

I did give all the correct inputs but couldn't able to run the feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader classLoader=getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourceLoader resourceLoader=new MultiLoader(classLoader);
RuntimeOptionsFactory roFactory=new RuntimeOptionsFactory(getClass());
RuntimeOptions ro=roFactory.create();
ro.getGlue().clear();
ro.getGlue().add("applications.StepDefinitions");    
ro.getFeaturePaths().clear();
String feature = "src/applications/Features";  
ro.getFeaturePaths().add(feature);
ro.getFilters().add("@Scenario1");
ClassFinder classFinder=new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader,classLoader);
cucumber.runtime.Runtime runtime=new cucumber.runtime.Runtime(resourceLoader,classFinder,classLoader,ro);
try {    
runtime.run();
}
catch (RuntimeException ex) {
throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}


and also updated the gherkin jar to 2.12.2 and this worked fine
```